# Hyper-parameter search for time series LSTM-RNN using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, lstm

This question is about tuning the hyper-parameters of a LSTM-RNN on tensorflow. I would like to know about an approach to finding the best hyper-parameters for your RNN.

I am working on a dataset to predict monsoon patterns in central India.

My time-series plot looks like this.
[image: Time series plot]

My goal is to predict the value of rainfall of a day 30 days in advance.

Currently I have the following hyper-parameters.

```
num_days = 30 #number of days used to make next prediction
lstm_size=256
num_layers=2
keep_prob=0.8
batch_size = 50
init_learning_rate = 0.03
learning_rate_decay = 0.99
init_epoch = 5
max_epoch = 1000
```

Based on the time-series plot what is a good choice for my given hyper-parameters?